# How I can serialize Soap body with multiple XmlElementAttribute?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I used **Add Service Reference** and add wsdl which create file `Reference.cs` with any class and decorate  property with two XmlElementAttribute.

How I populate Item with filterByUser and includeSites so send to webserver soap?

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.3761.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="orghierarchy.interfaces.com")]
public partial class GetOrgHierarchyRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private object itemField;        

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("filterByUser", typeof(string), Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("includeSites", typeof(bool), Order=0)]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
            propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `XmlElementAttribute`s are for selecting which field name to use by type of value set to the `Item` property.

```
var obj = new GetOrgHierarchyRequest
{
    Item = "123"
};
```

produces XML:

```
<GetOrgHierarchyRequest>
  <filterByUser xmlns="orghierarchy.interfaces.com">123</filterByUser>
</GetOrgHierarchyRequest>
```

And

```
var obj = new GetOrgHierarchyRequest
{
    Item = true
};
```

produces

```
<GetOrgHierarchyRequest>
  <includeSites xmlns="orghierarchy.interfaces.com">true</includeSites>
</GetOrgHierarchyRequest>
```